# Invalid CRON expression 0 */8 * * *

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch, kubernetes-cronjob

I am trying to use AWS Cloudwatch service. Inside that I am create a Synthetic Canary.

And for the schedule I am inserting a cron job with value `0 */8 * * *` .

Basically I want to execute it every 8 Hours, Every Day.

But the AWS Cron checker tells that it is wrong expression. I've checked various links but everywhere same expression is there.

I am not sure what is wrong with above expression.

[image]

Comment: bot the aws doc and crontab.guru are saying you are right... did you try ```0 0/8 * * *``` ?


Looks like an aws problem to me...

Comment: @fun_times just tried it, no luck. Same error.

Comment: open a support ticket? (if commercial account)

Comment: just a thought, could you have non-breaking space in there? it happens to the best of us... add the spaces manually to be sure...

Comment: @fun_times it's a personal account, checked for spaces. No Luck.

Comment: out of ideas, sorry

Comment: no worries @fun_times. I tried `0 */8 ? * *` and this is working. But not sure what `?` does

Comment: As per AWS it is At 0 minutes past the hour, every 8 hours, every day

Answer (score 2):

If this needs to be executed every 8 hours, then you can Schedule expressions using the `rate` as provided [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html).

For CRON expression will be:

```
0 0/8 * * ? *
```

You can read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html) more.

Comment: aahh, right, the aws cron does not allow Day-of-month and Day-of-week both being ```*``` I just read it and ignored it as I was focusing on the hour field and * * is allowed in regular cron...

Comment: @shivkumar this is also not working.  I tried `0 */8 ? * *` and it is working. do you know why? and what is the use of `?`.

Comment: not sure if `0 */8 ? * *` is correct expression to run every 8 hours. As per AWS it is At 0 minutes past the hour, every 8 hours, every day

Comment: See the placement of ?